# How do I build a .deb without zstd compression in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I'm building a .deb using `dpkg-buildpackage` on Ubuntu 21.10 that is then extracted in a Debian system, which does not use zstd compression. How can I switch to the old compression when building my deb?

Running the command with `--compression=xz` or the equivalent `-Z` flag still leads to a zstd compressed file.

Comment: I also cam across this and tried the compression flag, but it did not worked. Did you managed to came up with a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry no, my "solution" was to use a Docker container running an older Ubuntu version

Comment: Thank you for the response. Got now another compression format in my debian package, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make dpkg use another compression format by adding the following lines to the rules file, which is located in your debian folder:

```
override_dh_builddeb:
    dh_builddeb -- -Zgzip
```

It is a bit late, but I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Thanks! Could you update your answer to include the location of the debian/rules file?

Comment: The debian folder is in your project, which you want to build. Inside the debian folder, there is a rules file. You just have to append the text.

Comment: Thanks! Note that indent must be tab, not spaces. Using spaces will cause a '*** missing separator' error

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `dpkg-deb` to build your deb add `-Zxz` to change the compression method from zstd to xz.

`dpkg-deb -Zxz --build --root-owner-group yourdeb_1.1-0_amd64`