# JFrog not showing any 'Debian Info' for package built on Ubuntu Jammy

Tags: artifactory, dpkg-buildpackage

I am trying to build a custom debian package of the Cassandra C++ Driver on Jammy (22.04) [0].

It builds fine, but when I manually 'Deploy' the packages to our private JFrog repo no information is shown in the 'Debian Info' section, and the packages are not picked up when I do `sudo apt update` locally.

Locally doing a `dpkg-deb -I <package.deb>` shows all the expected information. Also, installing the local package with `sudo dpkg -i <package.deb>` works fine.

All seems fine when I perform the same actions on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04)

There's nothing in the JFrog UI that indicates any issue with the package.

How can I figure out what's going wrong?

[0] https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver
`cd` to 'packaging' and run `build_deb.sh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello I came across the same issue and found out the problem, since ubuntu 21.10 the default package compression method has changed to zstd but artifactory had no support of this until recently: [RTFAC-19541](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-19541).

So you can either update your artifactory instance to at least version 7.38.0 or use another compression method in your debian package generation process, see the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196872/how-do-i-build-a-deb-without-zstd-compression-in-ubuntu-21-10).

Too bad that artifactory didn't print any error for this.